# Android overscroll bounce animation on gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create a over scroll bounce animation in `GridView`.

I have searched for a long time but still could not find a way to implement a over   scroll bounce animation to my `GridView` , I came across with the flow home launcher and wonder how did the devs achieve that animation when scrolling the app list , it would be better if i can attach a video .

I realise that there are many apps doing this over scroll animation but how?

The following screenshorts is the flow home launcher

[image: normal]
[image: overscroll]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps [this repo on GitHub](https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor) - which provides the over-scroll 'bounce' effect it seems you're looking for, could do the trick for you.

It works well on many scrollable core Android views - one of which is GridView:

Given a GridView object at hand, you could apply the effect as follows:

```
GridView gridView = ...
OverScrollDecoratorHelper.setUpOverScroll(gridView);
```

Note: you haven't specified what the context is. Assuming you're implementing an Activity, this should be done upon creation (i.e. in onCreate()).

To include it in your project, add this to your project's gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Thx , i will try that

Comment: Thx for the elaboration and the library really helps me